# What is the correct way to acquire Service Principal via Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sdk

I acquire microsoft oauth2 with the scope `https://management.azure.com//.default` which is for managing azure services. When I authorize the app a service principal for the app gets created which I need for working with Azure services.

How can I get this service principal via Azure SDK? From what I've found the only way is through the Graph API but the Graph RBAC (part of Azure SDK) announced as deprecated, so I don't want to rely on it and I can't use MS Graph SDK because its oauth2 scope conflicts with the Azure scope (you can't authorize both Azure and Graph SDK). So, what's the correct approach here?

Comment: Can you help us understand a bit  more about what your scenario?  Are you looking to retrieve the principal itself for some reason, or just use it to authorize working with Azure SDK clients?

Comment: @JesseSquire my app helps people deploying their apps on Azure, so when I create new resources via ARM from my app I want them to be "created/owned by this app" which as I understand can be achieved by specifying service principal client id. Now I need to get the service principal that was automatically created when a user authorized my app

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is not be available right now, but you might file a feature request with feature team, [Feature Request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net#feature-requests)

Answer (score -1):

To get the **Service Principal** by using **PowerShell** or **Azure CLI** Except **MS Graph**

#### Using PowerShell

```
# Get all SP using Top Filter to fetch specific no of SP
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [-Filter <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]

# Using SearchString to fetch the exact SP
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
   [-SearchString <String>]
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [<CommonParameters>]

# Using Object ID
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
   -ObjectId <String>
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Refer to [Get SP using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0)

#### Using Azure CLI

```
az ad sp list --show-mine --query "[].{id:appId, tenant:appOwnerTenantId}"
```

##### You can use the below properties to filter and Get the Specific SP

- **--display-name** - Looks for service principals with the same prefix as the given name. The value set with the **--name** parameter during creation is the service principal's display name. The name prefix is azure-cli- if you didn't specify —name while creating the service principal.
- **--sp** -  Filter that matches exact service principal names. The principal name of service always begins with `https://`. If you didn't use a URI for —name, this value is `https://` followed by the display name.
- **--show-mine** - Service principals generated by the **signed-in user** are requested with **—show-mine**.
- **--filter** - Performs **server-side filtering** using an OData filter. This method is preferred over using the CLI's —query parameter to filter data on the client-side.

Refer to [Get SP using CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli#2-get-an-existing-service-principal)

Comment: I asked specifically about Azure SDK

Comment: Currently, there are 3 ways (CLI, Powershell, MS Graph)to get the SP.

Comment: @chingis, Did you get a lead on your question. AFAIK, Currently, it is not available. The possible ways I am given as an answer.

Comment: thank you for your response but as I said your answer doesn't really address my question. I realize there's currently no way to get a service principal using the "azure service management" authorization which is in itself is *ridiculous* in my opinion considering that SP is something that you're expected to use while working with Azure services via SDK (see example in my comment to this question). I wanted to highlight this issue to Microsoft team and I don't know more appropriate place to do this, obviously it's not an SDK issue, it's an API design issue from my point of view